# Problem with numeric Excel's NumberFormat in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, format

I tried to set NumberFormat in a column:

```
_worksheet.Columns[index].NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";
```

but I have the result (custom format):

[image]

This is similar to recorded macro in the Excel VBA:

```
Columns(25).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

and I have the result (numeric format):
[image]

Where is the problem in my first code?
How to set the numeric format?

I have the MS Excel 2016.

EDIT:
When I try to write the number in a formated cell, I have the view:
[image]

When I record setup format which I setup by VS, I have the result:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "#.##0\.00"
```

Comment: Try deleting the custom format and then run code again.  Does it work then?

Comment: @NewHorse,  is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, your code can set the numeric format successfully.

Also, I find that you can use `NumberFormatLocal` to set the format.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
            Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open("E:\\1.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
            worksheet.Columns[1].NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";
            worksheet.Columns[2].NumberFormatLocal= "#,##0.00";
            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
```

You can see the following result:(123.456 ->123.46 ;456.789->456.79 and format is
Number)

[image]

Comment: The NumberFormatLocal gives me the same result.
I don't know wat is going on.

Comment: @NewHorse, the code works for me, based on this situation, I suggest that you can change to a new xlsx to check the file if has the same problem.